# Cannot resolve symbol 'BCrypt'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, bcrypt

I am trying to add BCrypt to my code, but my program won't import the dependency. All I get is the message "Cannot resolve symbol 'BCrypt'" and if I try to look at the informationsymbol, my only alternatives are:

- "Create class 'BCrypt'"
- "Create field 'BCrypt' in 'JavaclassName'"
- "Create local variable 'BCrypt'"
  and so on...

I tried adding dependency in the pom.xml-file:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

but it did not help.
I also tried:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
    <version>0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

but this just gave me red warnign-signs.

I use Intellij, and started a Spring project with SDK java version 11.
Hope someone is able to help :)

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are getting the error?

Comment: What import statement are you using?

Comment: I think it's an IDE issue, I often experience this kind of problem with the last releases of IntelliJ. I don't know why but the last versions of IntelliJ Ultimate (since 2020.1) seem really instable. To solve it, check your module SDK (not the project SDK) sometimes they are not the same. Also, you can invalidate the cache and restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try with

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
<version>5.4.6</version>
```

Comment: This works for me. 
The version which did not work:     <version>5.5.2</version>

Answer (score 0):

The following dependency works for me.

Try adding this, refreshing maven dependencies and restarting your IDE.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure my contribution will help you.
I've tried many answers to fix a similar issue, but the source for bcrypt I've used is different. The below code worked for me in VSCode.
In pom.xml file(within dependencies):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>at.favre.lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcrypt</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.2</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</dependency>
```

Also, this is what the import looks like:

```java
import at.favre.lib.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt;
```

Link to the source for this version of BCrypt.
https://github.com/patrickfav/bcrypt
I hope this helps someone.